# How to show that there is no surjection between $Z \oplus Z$ to $Z_m \times Z_n \times Z_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to show that there is no surjection between $Z \oplus Z$ to $Z_m \times Z_n \times Z_p$?.

Intuitively, $Z_m \times Z_n \times Z_p$, if there is such a surjection then $Z_m \times Z_n \times Z_p$ can be generated by two elements, but  $Z_m \times Z_n \times Z_p$ "has to be generated by at least three elements". How to formalize this idea?

EDIT: The original question is that if $G = \oplus_{i=1}^{n} Z_{p^{k_i}}$, $k_1 \geq k_2 \geq \ldots \geq k_n$, and there are two elements in $G$ that generates $G$, then $n$ can at most be $2$.($p$ here is a prime)

Comment: Are any of $m,n,p$ co-prime to each other?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: I assume you mean surjective homomorphism? Also, there is such a homomorphism for some triples $(m,n,p)$, are there other conditions or do you just want to find find some case for which no such homomorphism exists?

Comment: This rather depends on what $m$, $n$ and $p$ are.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Tensor with $\Bbb{Z}/(p)$.

Comment: what do you mean? @jgon

Answer (score 4):

If $m$ and $n$ are coprime a way to state the Chinese Remainder Theorem is that the natural map
$$
\Bbb Z\longrightarrow\Bbb Z_m\times\Bbb Z_n
$$
is surjective. Using this you can construct surjective maps as in the question for many triples $(m,n,p)$.

This was written BEFORE the question was edited.

Comment: I am sorry, but I was not fast enough to edit before you posted the answer.